# Check divisibility using Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, numbers, division

I want to know if it's possible to check divisibilitiy of a number using machine learning.
For example- Suppose I want to check numbers which are divisible by 11 and 13.
I could make a dataset of numbers from 1-500 and give them a label of 1 if they are divisible by 11, 2 if they are divisible by 13 and 0 if they aren't divisible by either.

Following are the problems I faced:

1. With numbers 1-500 the label 0 is obviously going to be the dominant label leading to biasing
2. Even when I keep a balanced dataset containing equal rows of all labels, when I apply the algo on 1-1000, lower range numbers are getting 0 as label, mid range numbers as 1 and higher range numbers as 2.

Would like to know what should I do to train my machine? Do I add new features? If yes, then what features?
Also if there is any ML algo that you think would work, please suggest (Have already tried KNN, Decision trees, SVM, Naive_Bayes)

EDIT: I know it's not a problem to apply ML but my professor has given me this assignment. And i was wondering if it's possible.

Comment: `eg` is an abbreviation for `exempli gratia,` which means `for example` in Latin.  Therefore `For eg` means `For for example,` i.e. it makes no sense.  Just say `eg` or `for example`

Comment: This is a classical "I have no idea what I'm doing, but Neural networks are supposed to be cool". Really. Finding the divisability of a number is one or two basic mathematical operations for a processor. Throwing a DNN at this problem is a sign of not having understood what DNNs do. And the fact that you couldn't make a linear operator give you a linear operation means you have not even tried to look at the math.

Comment: This is a really odd choice for application of a ML algorithm. Pretty much all ML classifiers will be bad at this (linear ones will fail), whilst it is trivially done as a built-in by most languages (including Pythons `%` operator for modular arithmetic). Could you add motivation? If it is about learning how ML works, really you are not adding much here that you could not do by learning XOR.

Comment: @NeilSlater they will not inherently be bad at it: Think about a vector of the first N numbers (including 0). Simply reshape that vector to a matrix where only the first  11 columns are filled with the elements from the vector (let's put it like this: the reshape(input, ×,11) matrix is embedded); then, just multiply that matrix with a matrix that "selects" the entries from the first column.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Obviously, if you need to find the matrix that transforms the number vector to the 11-column vector first and do that by starting with a random matrix and then hoping that the band structure would manifest by itself by autoconvolution... OK, that's not likely to converge fast.

Comment: I know it's not a problem to apply ML but my professor has given me this assignment. And i was wondering if it's possible.

Comment: This is the exact question i got- Write a machine learning algorithm to predict all numbers between 1 to 1000 which are divisible by 7, 11 and 77. Specifically, your output should return three different arrays, one containing all numbers which are divisible by 7, second one with all numbers divisible by 11 and the third containing all numbers divisible by 77.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yes, OK, I meant "inherently bad at generalising the problem". There are no basic, generic stats-based ML algorithms that will "learn division" (advanced ones, e.g. maybe RNNs working on a binary representation could do, but clearly not within OP's reach). Instead you can only teach them the division characteristics of the training set.

Comment: @NikhilNair: So this is a homework problem? What relevant subjects have you been taught? It is likely that you are being expected to apply knowledge from specific lessons or sources. I would expect non-linear classifiers (SVM with kernels, decision trees) to be able to learn this task on a training set - please share your approach and results, as it is possible you just have a mistake in your approach and it is much better question to identify and fix that, than have someone show you a solution.

Comment: Following was my approach:
I made a training dataframe with columns- Number, Label for numbers from 1-500. Label =0(if not divisible by either 7,11,77)
                    Label =1 (if divisible by 7)
                    Label=2 (if divisible by 11)
                    Label=3( If divisible by both 7 and 11)
After training with SVM/ Decision tree, when I applied the model on a list of numbers from 1-1000, the model assigned all the numbers, label 0

Comment: Alternatively I also tried to balance the labels by making sure each label has 100 entries by applying it in range(5000,10000) .

Still somehow it had a bias of 0 on all entries in 1-1000(Which I suspect is because label 0 was the dominating label for lower numbers)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the main problem is to encode the integers - of course using the integers themselves doesn't make any sense, so you'd need to encode them appropriately.

If you think about integers (from some range) in binary they naturally belong to appropriate vector space, and machine learning algorithms assume that inputs are such vectors.

BTW  Some teachers use something similar as a toy problem in machine learning, for example [17th slide from this pdf](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/csc2535/notes/lec10new.pdf) by Hinton's course.